# Copied image using execCommand not pasting everywhere

Tags: javascript, image

I am trying to create a copy image functionality using the following code:

```js
// Code goes here

function CopyImageById(Id) 
{
  const imgs = document.createElement('img');
  imgs.src = document.getElementById(Id).src;
  
  //alert ('Create image') ;

  const bodys = document.body ;
  bodys.appendChild(imgs);
  //alert ('Image on document')
  
  let myrange;
  if (document.createRange)  
  {
    //alert ('CreateRange work');
    myrange = document.createRange();
    myrange.setStartBefore(imgs);
    myrange.setEndAfter(imgs);
    myrange.selectNode(imgs);

  }
  else
  {
    alert ('CreateRange not working');
  }
  
  const sel = window.getSelection();
  sel.addRange(myrange);

  const successful = document.execCommand('copy');

  const msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
  //alert('Copy image command was ' + msg);
  
  bodys.removeChild(imgs);
  document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML="Copy image command was " + msg ;
}
```

Reproducer: http://jsfiddle.net/xz14jp3f/

The copied image however is only pasting on word document such as google doc, but not on all the places such slack or stackoverflow. If you copy the image using the chrome's right click context menu option to copy the image, we can paste it everywhere.

How can I fix this?